# Status meaning: report on revised version promised by referee

Tags: publications, paper-submission

Status of my submitted paper has changed to:

- 28 November: Sent to referee 1
- 28 November: Sent to referee 2
- 28 November: Sent to referee 3
- 29 November: Report expected from referee 2
- 29 November: Report on revised version promised by referee 2

What's the meaning of last status? Considering that  I haven't submitted a revised version yet!

Comment: When did you submit the paper? Is it to a publisher that appears on Beall's list of predatory publishers?

Comment: October 16. It's IFP Energies nouvelles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flippant: It means Referee 2 has promised a report on the revised version.

I'd normally say that this *probably* means that Referee 2's review is overdue, they have been contacted by the editorial office, and they've said it's coming. However, given the short time frame, unless you have submitted to a journal with an extraordinarily fast turnaround, this isn't likely the case.

With your added information, and that only one referee has appeared in the status, that likely means they have accepted the review. The updated status *may* mean that the referee has given the journal a head's up that the report is coming, but that it's delayed in some way that they know in advance (hence the "promised") and the editor selected the wrong status. It may also mean that something went wrong in the initial dispatch of your manuscript and they had to fix something (hence "revised) - I have, for example, had a supplemental file go missing in a packet sent to me.

But all of this is idle speculation - no one here can really *know* what it means.

My advice? It's been one day since your paper was sent for review. Stop checking on its status.

Comment: Well, I haven't submitted a revised version yet!

Comment: @Ghartal That is useful context that you may wish to include in your opening post. I will edit my answer shortly to reflect that.

Comment: Oh there is one more point to mention in opening post! Please wait for my edit!

Comment: @Ghartal Yeah...no offense but you *seriously* missed some important context with your first version.

Comment: No problem! So the referee says he/she doesn't even look at it! Paper is not that bad really!

Comment: @Ghartal You really can't know that.